# What is the return value of telldir() function?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    DIR *dir=opendir("dir");
    struct dirent *dent;
    while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL){
            printf("Filename: %s\t\t Location in Directory Stream: %ld\n",
                    dent->d_name,telldir(dir));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
Filename: b.txt              Location in Directory Stream: 32
Filename: a.txt              Location in Directory Stream: 64
Filename: d.c                Location in Directory Stream: 96
Filename: .                  Location in Directory Stream: 128
Filename: test               Location in Directory Stream: 160
Filename: ..                 Location in Directory Stream: 192
$
```

In the above program the return value of `telldir()` function is multiples of 32. As per the reference to man page for `telldir()`
is "return current location in directory stream". So, I expect like the directory contains 5 files, so at first call to `telldir()` returns 1 and
in next call it return 2. But here the output is in multiples of 32. Why is the output like this? And why does the `telldir()` function return this kind of value?

Comment: You might want to read the **Notes** section in [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/telldir.3.html).

Comment: it is similar to man page. No more additional information is not mentioned there.

Comment: From the [linked manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/telldir.3.html): "Modern filesystems use tree or hash structures, rather than flat tables, to represent directories.  On such filesystems, the value returned by telldir() (and used internally by readdir(3)) is a "cookie" that is used by the implementation to derive a position within a directory.  ***Application programs should treat this strictly as an opaque value, making no assumptions about its contents***." The `telldir` function returns a value, what that value is doesn't matter, don't interpret it in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing POSIX [states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/seekdir.html) about "location" returned by `telldir()` is:

> The seekdir() function shall set the position of the next readdir() operation on the directory stream specified by dirp to the position specified by loc. The value of loc should have been returned from an earlier call to telldir(). The new position reverts to the one associated with the directory stream when telldir() was performed.
>
> If the value of loc was not obtained from an earlier call to telldir(), or if a call to rewinddir() occurred between the call to telldir() and the call to seekdir(), the results of subsequent calls to readdir() are unspecified.

Thus, return values of `telldir()` are implementation-defined. It is *not* the number of current file.

---

If you look at glibc implementation, you'll see that:

- for [some hosts](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/bsd/telldir.c), `telldir()` returns a cookie based on global counter which is incremented every `telldir()` call (for any directory);
- for [other hosts](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/telldir.c), including Linux, `telldir()` returns a "file offset" which [is later passed](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/seekdir.c) to `lseek()`.

Even if `telldir()` returns "file offset", this offset may has special meaning for a directory, depending of filesystem implementation.

For example, for `ext4` see [`ext4_dir_llseek()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/dir.c#L335):

> ext4_dir_llseek() calls generic_file_llseek_size to handle htree directories, where the "offset" is in terms of the filename hash value instead of the byte offset.

---

In my system, example output of your program is (for `ext4`):

```
Filename: ..         Location in Directory Stream: 3540738803800888240
Filename: foo        Location in Directory Stream: 5674377099084065539
Filename: .          Location in Directory Stream: 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

The `telldir()` function returns the position in the directory, the code may be like:

```
    long int
    telldir (DIR *dirp)
    {
      return dirp->filepos;
    }
```

When you call `opendir()`, the filepos is 0, then `readdir()` will call `gentdents()`, and add `dirp->filepos`. For example after calling `readdir()`, then `dirp->filepos = dp->d_off`, the `dp->d_off` will be set by `file->f_op->iterate()`. For the filesystem PFS (a filesystem driver for linux designed by myself), `iterate()` is `pfs_readdir()`:

```
static int
pfs_readdir(struct file *file, struct dir_context *ctx)
{
        int64_t dno;
        unsigned long off;
        struct buffer_head *bh;
        struct pfs_dir_entry *de;
        struct inode *inode = file_inode(file);

        if(ctx->pos == 0)
                ctx->pos = PFS_DIRHASHSIZ * sizeof(int64_t) + sizeof(int64_t);
        for(off = ctx->pos & (PFS_BLOCKSIZ - 1); ctx->pos < inode->i_size; off = ctx->pos & (PFS_BLOCKSIZ - 1)){
                if(!(dno = pfs_get_block_number(inode, pfs_block_number(ctx->pos), 0)))
                        goto skip;
                if(!(bh = sb_bread(inode->i_sb, dno / PFS_STRS_PER_BLOCK))){
                        pr_err("pfs: device %s: %s: failed to read block %lld of dir %lld\n",
                                inode->i_sb->s_id, "pfs_readdir", pfs_block_number(ctx->pos), PFS_I(inode)->i_ino);
                        goto skip;
                }
                do{
                        de = (struct pfs_dir_entry *)((char *)bh->b_data + off);
                        if(de->d_ino){
                                if(!(dir_emit(ctx, pfs_get_de_name(de), de->d_len, (int32_t)le64_to_cpu(de->d_ino), DT_UNKNOWN))){
                                        brelse(bh);
                                        return 0;
                                }
                        }
                        off += pfs_get_de_size(de);
                        ctx->pos += pfs_get_de_size(de);
                }while(off < PFS_BLOCKSIZ && ctx->pos < inode->i_size);
                brelse(bh);
                continue;
skip:
                ctx->pos += PFS_BLOCKSIZ - off;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

`dp->d_off` is set by `dir_emit()`, source is:

```
static inline bool dir_emit(struct dir_context *ctx, const char *name, int namelen, u64 ino, unsigned type)
{
         return ctx->actor(ctx, name, namelen, ctx->pos, ino, type) == 0;
}
```

As you see, the `ctx->actor` will call `filldir()`, and `filldir() will set`dp - previous`and call`__put_user(ctx->pos, &dp->d_off)`, then the`dp->d_off`is set (as you see, the`ctx->pos`is the offset of previous entry's end), and`telldir()`will return the position of the last entry you got via`readdir()`.

NB `void main()` is not a good way, you can use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. instead.